# .Net - Display multiple placeholders within in a table

Tags: asp.net

We are using the below code. We want these two placeholder to display next to each other. But when we run this, Placeholder1 comes underneath Placeholder2.

Requirement is to place both placeholder next to each other

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
```

HTML generated by code:

```
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <br />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table border='1' class='table table-striped'  width='450'><tr><th>Document Name</th><td>LMA2.doc</td></tr><tr><th>Uploaded Date</th><td>01 Aug 2018</td></tr></table><table border='1' class='table table-striped' width='450px'><tr><th>Facilities</th><th>Size</th><th>InterestRate</th></tr><tr ><td>A</td><td>11 million</td><td>8</td></tr><tr ><td>B</td><td>15 million</td><td>4.5</td></tr><tr ><td>C</td><td>20 million</td><td>6.6</td></tr></table>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

CSS:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .02);
    width:800px;*/
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: well, what are you putting into the placeholder? On its own, a placeholder doesn't render anything.

Comment: Code behind adds table to these placeholder. Both placeholders fetch data from different tables. We r struggling with positioning..

Comment: please show the completed HTML generated by the placeholder, and any CSS you've written which would affect table elements. Positioning is determined by relationship between the final HTML and CSS. The fact you used a placeholder to insert the HTML is irrelevant.

Comment: add html and css... see if this helps to find the issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/osz5xrfy/ - I'm not seeing the problem. All the data is in the second placeholder. The first one just contains a `<br/>` which will produce a new line, but only within the table cell it's been placed into. There's not anything visible to actually place side by side. If there was, they'd be side by side: http://jsfiddle.net/osz5xrfy/3/ . BTW, you know that tables within tables for making layout went out of fashion in about 2005 when browsers started to get better at rendering. You can use divs and CSS to do it nicely and semantically, and more flexibily.

Comment: You should look into a GridView Control. It renders a html table. It's much easier that creating your own.